# Multi-tap/multi-press/triple-tap algorithm

Tags: c#, java, .net, algorithm, input

One of our kiosk applications lacks a physical keyboard and we need to add text entry to it. Since it only has a numeric pad attached, we figured we might as well use the old cell phone entry method. I've been able to find out that it's called multitap (go figure), but I can't find any algorithm implementations. Does anyone know of any?

(I can't limit the input to a dictionary, so I can't use T9-like approaches)

Comment: This could be a fun algorithm to express as a [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but a neat paper on a similar input method: http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~jj/jannotti.com/papers/iconic-uist02/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a timer in combination with an int to count the taps. This is pure pseudo code but will give the basic idea.

```
long lastEvent = 0;
int lastNum = 0;
int taps = 0;


eventListener(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == lastNum)
    {
         if ((DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() - lastEvent) < AppropriateTimeLimit)
         {
              taps++;
         }
         else
         {
              GetLetter(taps, lastNum);
              lastEvant = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
              taps = 0;
         }
    }
    else
    {
              GetLetter(taps, lastNum);
              lastEvant = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
              taps = 0;
              lastNum = e.Value;
    }
}

char GetLetter(int taps, int num)
{
     if (num == 1)
         return punctuationVals[taps % length -1];
     else if (num == 0)
         return ' '; //from what I remember 0 was for spaces on most phones
     else
     {
         int val;
         if (taps > 3)
             val = taps % 4; // old phones wrap around back to the first char if I press the key 5 times
         else 
             val = taps;
          return values[num][val];
     }

}

char[][] values = new char[9][4]; // statically code all of your chars in these arrays
char[] punctuationVals = new char[idkHowMany];
```

So here's the design overview. Firstly, we have an event listener that is handling all the input events. We know a tap sequence is complete under one of two conditions 1) Time has expired (If you remember typing on old phones if I wanted to type 'abc' I'd have to press 2 once, wait a second or so, press 2 twice wait another second, press 2 three times) or 2) A new key has been pressed.

In either case we need to know what the last key pressed was so we track that. If the key input does not match the last key pressed then we can safely output the last key pressed, thus we call `GetLetter`, reset the taps to 0, set the last even time to now, and set the `lastNum` to the number that was just pressed. This is the simpler case.

In the case of someone trying to input 'abc' we need to know when to distinguish between the end of the first input and start of the next. For this we use a timer. If the difference between the first tap and the one which just occurred is within some limit (perhaps half a second or a second) then we increment the taps, if it's outside of it, we decide that they've moved on from 'a' to 'b' at which point we go through the same output process as when the user presses a key different from the last, except we don't change the value of the last key pressed since it hasn't changed.

`GetLetter` is the last thing worth discussing. This is fairly simple, you hard code a 2D array for values 2-9, to make indexing simple we'll retain 0 and 1 but leave them blank.

Meaning, the array is something like;

```
  '', '','', ''
  '', '', '', ''
  '2', 'a', 'b', 'c' 
  '3', 'd', 'e', 'f'
  //ect
```

This makes indexing simpler, `GetLetter(2, 2)` simply returns `values[2][2]` which is correctly 'b'.

Because 7 successive taps on the 2 key would produce 'c' we do mod 4 on the value if it's greater than 3 (three because 4 % 4 is 0 which should produce the number itself which I have at index 0). Now `GetLetter(6, 2)` will return `values[2][2]` which is correctly 'b'.

1 is a special case. For that we just use a one dimensional array with however many values (maybe 20 or something) and we do modulus on it's input as well but obviously it's based of the length of that array. The modulus I have for this case may be wrong, but it would be simple to fix.

Answer (score 1):

so each button excluding the zero works in increaments of 4.  so it does not matter how many clicks on a certain keypad number , just divide it by 4 and take the remainder, 1=number,2=first letter, 3=second letter,0 = third letter.   Then depending on how many symbols you wish to allow the user to use you can use the same concept for the keypad 0 and  its symbols

1-a-b-c

2-d-e-f

3-g-h-i

4-j-k-l

5-m-n-o

6-p-q-r

7-s-t-u

8-v-w-x

9-y-z-WhiteSpace

0-symbols

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quad tap, looking at the letters on my telephone dial pad.

I don't know if there's a standard for the asterisk and pound keys, but the letters could be put in a lookup table.

For example,

```
7 key, three taps, returns R
5 key, one tap, returns J
```

If you actually need the number, that was an extra tap.

```
7 key, five taps, returns 7
```

I believe the pound key on my ancient cell phone shifted from upper to lower case, and lower to upper case.  There was also a title case, that would produce an upper case letter and shift to lower case.

The asterisk key popped up a punctuation symbol table.  You could use the 2, 4, 6, and 8 keys to navigate the table and pick a symbol.

Comment: It's actually completely variant and requires modulus on every input. Old phones would have like 20 punctuation characters assigned to 1. If I wanted to type a '+' or '%' it would take like 15 taps.